# Tests failed after add 'belongs_to' to model in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Tests failed after add belongs_to in Rails

I have 2 models in Rails application:

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user # Test failed after add this string
  validates :content, length: { maximum: 140 }, presence: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :microposts

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

I added string "belongs_to :user" to model "Micropost". After that I ran tests, and they failed:

```
rails test

  1) Failure:
MicropostsControllerTest#test_should_create_micropost [/home/kiselev/project/toy_app/test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:19]:
"Micropost.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 3
  Actual: 2

  2) Failure:
MicropostsControllerTest#test_should_update_micropost [/home/kiselev/project/toy_app/test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:38]:
Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
```

I have these 2 tests:

```
test "should create micropost" do
  assert_difference('Micropost.count') do
    post microposts_url, params: { micropost: { content: @micropost.content, user_id: @micropost.user_id } }
  end

  assert_redirected_to micropost_url(Micropost.last)
end

test "should update micropost" do
  patch micropost_url(@micropost), params: { micropost: { content: @micropost.content, user_id: @micropost.user_id } }
  assert_redirected_to micropost_url(@micropost)
end
```

I have a controller "MicropostsController":

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_micropost, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # POST /microposts
  # POST /microposts.json
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.new(micropost_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.save
        format.html { redirect_to @micropost, notice: 'Micropost was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @micropost }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /microposts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /microposts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.update(micropost_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @micropost, notice: 'Micropost was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @micropost }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Setup micropost:

```
class MicropostsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
setup do
  @micropost = microposts(:one)
end
```

Params in Micropost controller:

```
def micropost_params
  params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :user_id)
end
```

Fixtures Micropost:

```
one:
  content: MyText
  user_id: 1

two:
  content: MyText
  user_id: 1
```

How can I improve these tests to pass?

Comment: Can you add your controller code and code where ‘@micropost’ variable is defined in your tests?

Comment: @edariedl I've added some information about test and some method of controller.

Comment: I would like to see two more things `micropost_params` definition in the `MicropostsController` and fixtures definition for `microposts(:one)`

Comment: @edariedl I've added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[belongs_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) method adds among others also a presence validation for the `user`. Somewhere in the rails code it adds something like:

```rb
validates_presence_of :user
```

And it checks whether the user exists. In your fixtures you have set `user_id: 1`. But in your tests there is no user with 1 as an ID. To fix it you have to set correct user IDs for your microposts fixtures.

You can do it in the following way. You don't have to define `user_id`, you can define association in the fixtures:

```
one:
  content: MyText
  user: one

two:
  content: MyText
  user: one
```

Define a `user` key instead of `user_id` and as a value use the name of the fixture from the user fixtures - in tests it would be called `users(:one)` if you would want to access this fixture.

*Note: You can also remove the presence validation by adding `required: false` to your `belongs_to` definition but I would not recommend it.*

Comment: I am currently reading the Book Ruby on Rails Tutorial (3rd Edition) by Michael Hartl. The example seemed very similar but the recommended solution did not work. It did give me an idea of where else to try and looked at the fixture for the user and added the id: 1 and id:2 to the two entries and successfully solved the problem.